# how can i use to slack to start or stop a application

Tags: service, command, restart, slack

through slack i wanted to take actions-
start or stop a service present on my server.

eg -
to restart apache present on AWS server listening on 80 port.

any suggestion how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, use a bot. There are many bots for chat applications and Slack is one of the most supported.

I will personally recommend Hubot:

https://hubot.github.com/

You are going to have a lot to consider as this question is quite broad (probably why it has been voted down).

The documentation will get you started on installing the bot, then you can look at creating simple commands:

https://hubot.github.com/docs/

Then you will open a can of worms on security implications of who you want to allow the ability to restart apache etc etc.

I'd ask myself why am i restarting apache personally.

Comment: there is a requirement in which i don't want to login into the server.whenever any of my service gets into hung state or stop suddenly, i need to start or restart the service through slack.because of which we need a bot which we could integrate with slack.